# why don't i have the same fluids particles as others? (using M1 MAc)

Tags: physics

I'm using M1 Macbook Air, and I don't know if that is the reason I am not seeing the same features as this Youtube tutorial screenshot? I don't have obstacles, particles, control. All I have id Domain, Flow, and Effector.

[image]

Comment: what Blender version r u using and what Blender version is in the tutorial? linking the  tutorial would help....

Comment: This is the old fluid system before there was Mantaflow, so I guess you're watching a 2.79 tutorial or something. Although, the UI looks different so it might be a newer version. But it's not Mantaflow.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I wanted to make sure it's not because I'm using M1 chip laptop.

Comment: @samk It's always advisable to first check if the tutorial you're watching uses the version you're using. Some things might be working more or less the same over several versions, but some things drastically change from one to the next. Especially when I see something that doesn't seem to exist in my Blender I would first suspect a wrong version before a hardware mismatch. Of course there are things like no CUDA or OptiX support which are depending on the hardware...